# How many positive integers less than $2011$ cannot be expressed in the form $4a + 5b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

How would I solve the following question:

> How many positive integers less than $2011$ cannot be expressed in the form $4a + 5b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers?

I was trying to apply the [Chicken McNugget theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem) to it, but to no avail. Is there a simpler way to solve the question? (The answer is $13$ btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smallest is $9 = (1,1)$, then $13 = (2,1)$, $14 =(1,2)$, then $17 = (3,1)$, $18 = (2,2)$, $19 = (1,3)$, $21 = (4,1)$, $22=(3,2)$, $24 = (1,4)$ and $26 =(4,2)$, $27 = (3,3)$.

As it gets confusing let us look at a Cantor style diagram:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   9  13  17  21  25  29  33
2  14  18  22  26  30  34  38
3  19  23  27  31  35  39  43
4  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
5  29  33  37  41  45  49  53
6  34  38  42  46  50  54  58
7  39  43  47  51  55  59  63
```

That rules out $1$ to $8$, $10$, $11$, $12$, $15$, $16$, $20$, which seem to be $14$ numbers, hmm.

For the other numbers follow the diagonals.

The $k$-th diagonal spawns from $(k,1) = 4k+5$ down to $(1,k) = 4+5k$. (*)

We would need to show they contact / overlap from a certain $k$, I guess.

The lower end of the $k$-th diagonal $(1,k)$ is attaching the next diagonal, starting with the next upper end $(k+1,1)$, if:
$$
4+5k \ge (4(k+1) + 5) - 1 \iff 4 + 5k \ge 4k + 8 \iff k \ge 4
$$

The gaps can only happen in the first three diagonals, which limits the search space to $1$ to $20$. Upwards it is dense, so we can see the upper limit of $2011$ more as a distraction.

About (*):

The $i$ steps down the diagonal from $(k,1)$ to $(k-i, 1+i)$ change the value by
$$
\Delta = 4 [(k-i)-k] + 5 [(1+i)-1] = -4i + 5i = i
$$
so there is no gap within a diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It makes sense now. Looking at your solution, I'm pretty sure the answer is 14, maybe the answer key is wrong..., but nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: It turned out simpler than I thought first.

Answer (score 1):

According to Sylvester's theorem the largest number $n$ that cannot be written in the form
$$n=4x+5y, \qquad x, y\in{\Bbb N}_{\geq0}$$
is $n=4\cdot 5-4-5=11$. It follows that the largest $n$ which cannot be written in the form
$$n=4x+5y, \qquad x, y\in{\Bbb N}_{\geq1}\tag{1}$$
is $20$. Therefore let us check which numbers in $[20]$ *can* be represented in the form $(1)$. These are the six numbers
$$5+4, \quad 5+2\cdot 4,\quad 5+3\cdot 4,\quad 2\cdot 5+4,\quad 2\cdot 5+2\cdot 4, \quad 3\cdot 5+4\ .$$
It follows that $20-6={\bf 14}$ positive integers *cannot* be represented in the form $(1)$.